Подскажите, как получить цену из списка
Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить цену открытия, закрытия, итд. Не судите строго, только учусь.
Биржа MEXC
Тикер достать получилось.
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

async def mrlsv_ws():
    url = 'wss://wbs.mexc.com/ws'
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        print('Connected')
        subs = dict(
            method = 'SUBSCRIPTION',
            params = [
                'spot@public.kline.v3.api@BTCUSDT@Min30'
            ]
        )
        await ws.send(json.dumps(subs))
        async for msg in ws:
           
            msg = json.loads(msg)
            symbol = msg.get('s')
            print(symbol)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(mrlsv_ws())


response:
{
  'd': {
       'e': 'spot@public.kline.v3.api', 
       'k': {
             't': 1732906800, 
             'o': '97176',
             'c': '97047.99', 
             'h': '97190.48', 
             'l': '96879.53',
             'v': '75.0161855',
             'a': '7276917.78', 
             'T': 1732908600, 
             'i': 'Min30'
             }
        }, 
   'c': 'spot@public.kline.v3.api@BTCUSDT@Min30',
   't': 1732908001686, 
   's': 'BTCUSDT'
}  

Как получить d->k->o

либо symbol['d']['k']['o'] либо msq['s']['d']['k']['o'].

Интересный какой курс :)
У Вас вложенные словари. Вам надо несколько раз вызвать метод .get или последовательно обратится к словарям по ключам. Как-то так:
price_open = msg.get("d").get('k').get('o')
price_close = msg.get("d").get('k').get('c')

и так далее, меняете ключ в последнем вызове метода .get и получаете нужную цену.
Или так, через ключи:
price_open = msg['d']['k']['o']
price_close = msg['d']['k']['c']

Вторая запись короче, разница между ними, что если .get не найдет ключ, то вернет None. Во втором же случае, если ключ не найдется - будет исключение.

Все работает!
Спасибо !!!!!!!!!

@ProhodnayBaza вместо msg напишите symbol

@strawdog если автор получил тикер (в данном случае BTCUSDT) обратившись к словарю msg по ключу s, значит ключи d и s с одного уровня, это видно по респонсу. Значит надо msg[‘d’]…

@strawdog он нас запутал просто. У него в коде print(msg[‘s’]) должен вернуть тикер, то есть BTCUSDT, а он нам распечатал весь ответ сервера, то есть msg.
